# Weird blown out colours in renders eevee

Tags: rendering, export, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I have a weird problem with blown out colors when I render with atmosphere and bloom.

It's weird because I'm rendering a video with 300 frames, and the glitch shows up at about 30 random frames.
I can solve it by manually re-rendering all 30 glitched frames, but that is very inconvenient and it should be much easier.

this is how the glitch look like, The red blown out dot shouldn't be there.

[image: Photo with weird glitch]

This is how the frame should be

[image: enter image whitout glitch]

Here can you see a couple of glitch frames

[image]

I have this problem on multiple projects

Can somebody help me how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue as well, and it seems like it's an issue with using bloom and volumetrics at the same time.

Try clamping the bloom with a value of 20, see if that fixes it. (of course, you'll only know when rendering large batches of frames again)